# EWS push notification in node js

Tags: node.js, push-notification, exchangewebservices

I am writing node.js code trying to subscribe to a push notification using EWS API when new mail arrives into the Inbox folder. 
I succeed to subscribe to push notification by soap request (see soap request below) and got a subscribeId and watermark with the result, but, I can not understand how the exchange server sends the actual e-mail notifications back to my app.
Does anyone have any idea how to implement it in node js?
Most of the examples I found on the internet were implemented in C# (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73834/EWS-Mail-Notifier)

The soap request for subscripe push notification is:

```
<tns:Subscribe xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<tns:PushSubscriptionRequest>
<t:FolderIds>
<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/></t:FolderIds>
<t:EventTypes>
<t:EventType>NewMailEvent</t:EventType>
</t:EventTypes>
<t:StatusFrequency>1</t:StatusFrequency>
<t:URL>http://12.121.22.32:5050/exchange</t:URL>
</tns:PushSubscriptionRequest>
</tns:Subscribe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the Node stuff, but you will have to start an HTTP listener on the port/dir you specified in the subscription request above, 12.121.22.32:5050/exchange.  Exchange will POST a payload to you for each event you've subscribed to.  Hope this moves you a little further along...